# How to update MySQL database row with a click on link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**What I have**
A MySQL database with many rows. It contains an ID, name, score, and some other columns.

A website that shows a RANDOM item from this database. It will show on my page with all the corresponding data.

**What I want**
I want a person that visits my website to push a button that will increment my score with + 1.

**My code**

**update_value.php**

```
<?php
    include ('database_conn.php');
    $rowID = $row['ID'];
    $sql2 = "UPDATE database SET Score = Score + 1 WHERE ID = '$rowID'";
    $conn->query($sql2);
?>
```

**scripts.js** << is in js/scripts.js folder

```
$("#vote-up-q").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "update_value.php"
            })
            location.reload();
    });
```

**menu.php**

```
<span class="circle-thin-yo circle-down" id="vote-down-q">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="vote down">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
 </a>
</span>
```

The **database_conn.php** file contains a $conn like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

**Simply put:** someone can click the **div#vote-up-q** shown in **menu.php** and update the mysql value Score with previous Score + 1.

Comment: What is the value of `$row['ID']` ?  And where is that value assigned?

Comment: Where do you capture the ROW ID from the HTTP Request and where do you set it in your SQL query? Also , use PDO, not mysqli, you are wide open for SQL injections !

Comment: look at your js console and check for errors via php and the query.

Comment: I stared at this question long enough with no response to any comments or an updated question. Ping one of us when you have something more to share, good luck; I have left the question.

Comment: There is a new answer to your question, check it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood well, your webpage will display data of a random user, so, when the upvote button is clicked, this random user get their score incremented.

If this is the case, **you need to send the ID of the random user to the PHP script**. Example : copy-paste next codes in two PHP files and open the "html and ajax file" in your browser:

**html and ajax file**

```
<?php
$user_id = 28; // ◄■■ RANDOM USER FROM DATABASE.
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
function my_button ( user_id ) // ◄■■ RANDOM USER ID.
{ $.ajax( { type    : "POST",
            data    : { "my_id" : user_id }, // ◄■■ RANDOM USER ID.
            url     : "update_value.php",
            success : function ( data )
                      { alert( data );
                      },
            error   : function ( xhr )
                      { alert( "error" );
                      }
        } );
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="my_button('<?php echo $user_id;?>')"> <!-- ◄■■ RANDOM USER ID -->
            Upvote me!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**update_value.php**

```
<?php
    //include ('database_conn.php');
    $rowID = $_POST["my_id"]; // ◄■■ PARAMETER FROM AJAX.
    //$sql2 = "UPDATE database SET Score = Score + 1 WHERE ID = '$rowID'";
    //$conn->query($sql2);
    echo "User $rowID upvoted!";
?>
```

I commented the database lines in "update_value.php" for testing purposes.